# How to locate contours on a ringed shooting target

Tags: python, opencv, contour

Firstly, I am new to python and opencv so my understanding is limited, however I am trying to learn more as best I can.

I am currently struggling to locate contours(bullet holes) on a simple ringed target so that I can eventually score each hole. I have managed to solve a similar problem on a different image and I am wondering what I can do to get the same method to work on the new one.

[Successful attempt at scoring a target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Babdf.jpg)

[This is the target that my problem concerns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRSdP.png)

When I use these [HSV Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao5RG.png) I am presented with only the [Bullet Holes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRHPV.png). My limited knowledge tells me that perhaps these HSV values are useful in thresholding(?) but I can not seem to find the execution.

The method used to locate the contours in the example target is shown below:

```
imgREDUCED = cv2.inRange(image, (60, 60, 60), (150, 150, 150))

kernel = np.ones((10,10),np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(imgREDUCED, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

thresh = cv2.threshold(opening, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

for c in cnts:
    if cv2.contourArea(c) > 1:
        cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

What steps can I take to locate the contours on this new target image?
All help is appreciated and I will try my best to answer any questions

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable, in keeping with this site's purpose.

Answer (score 1):

By finding the bullseye and the outer ring we can calculate the score of each hole based on its distance from the center. Here are the steps I took to try and solve this.

First, I converted to HSV and took a look at the different channels:

Hue

[image]

Value

[image]

From the hue channel we can clearly see the holes in the target so it's a good candidate for thresholding for those. On the value channel we can clearly see the rings and the center so we'll use that channel to detect those.

Hue Mask (0, 30)

[image]

Value Mask (0, 155)

[image]

We can use findContours to outline the white parts of the mask. From that outline we can get the center of the contour and the area of the contour. Using this on the hue mask we get the center of each hole and using this on the value mask we can get the biggest ring by looking for the contour with the largest area. With the area of the biggest ring, we can estimate the radius via the circle's area formula.

To find the bullseye I thresholded the value mask again, but using the (215, 255) to search for high values. This perfectly captures just the center, but you might not always get that lucky with your pictures. Using the findContours function again I get the center are radius of the bullseye.

Now I can score each of the holes. I get the distance from the hole to the center and figure out where on the scoresheet it should land on.

Marked the outer ring, the center of each hole, the score of each hole, and the bullseye:

[image]

Here's the code:

```py
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np

# get center of contour
def centroid(contour):
    M = cv2.moments(contour);
    cx = int(round(M['m10']/M['m00']));
    cy = int(round(M['m01']/M['m00']));
    center = (cx, cy);
    return center;

# load image
img = cv2.imread("target.png");
img = img[:,:-1,:]; # there's a bit of wall or something on the right

# hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
h,s,v = cv2.split(hsv);

# find the outer ring
v_mask = cv2.inRange(v, 0, 155);

# contours
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(v_mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

# find the biggest contour
biggest_cntr = None;
biggest_area = 0;
marked = img.copy();
for contour in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour);
    if area > biggest_area:
        biggest_area = area;
        biggest_cntr = contour;
cv2.drawContours(marked, [biggest_cntr], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3);

# find biggest radius
big_radius = math.sqrt(biggest_area / math.pi);

# find center
center_v_mask = cv2.inRange(v, 215, 255);
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(center_v_mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
center = centroid(contours[0]);

# use this to calculate the middle radius
area = cv2.contourArea(contours[0]);
little_radius = math.sqrt(area / math.pi);

# draw center
marked = cv2.circle(marked, center, 2, (155,155,0), -1);

# mask holes
h_mask = cv2.inRange(h, 0, 30);
h_mask = cv2.medianBlur(h_mask, 11);

# draw contour centers
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(h_mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
holes = [];
for contour in contours:
    c = centroid(contour);
    holes.append(c);
    marked = cv2.circle(marked, c, 2, (0,0,155), -1);

# calculate approximate size of each ring
# (with foreknowledge that there are 9 + bullseye)
remaining_radius = big_radius - little_radius;
slices = remaining_radius / 9;

# calculate scores
scores = [];
for hole in holes:
    # get distance from center
    dx = hole[0] - center[0];
    dy = hole[1] - center[1];
    dist = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

    # check score
    dist -= little_radius;
    if dist < 0:
        scores.append(10);
    else:
        scores.append(9 - int(dist / slices));

# draw the scores
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX ;
for a in range(len(holes)):
    tup = (holes[a][0], holes[a][1]);
    marked = cv2.putText(marked, str(scores[a]), tup, font, 1, (0,0,155), 2, cv2.LINE_AA);

# show
cv2.imshow("marked", marked);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```

Comment: Thank you, this explanation is very useful as the method is well detailed. When transferring this method to my computer I am greeted with an error:                                 area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'contour'                                                        I received this after removing the underscores from the start of:                                                                       _, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(h_mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE); ) as i would receive a value error (expected 3, got 2)

Comment: What would you suggest I do to address the error?

Comment: right, sorry, I forgot to mention I'm in opencv 3.4. The findContours function returns different stuff depending on the version . What you did seems to be correct for the other major versions though. Try printing out the contour before calling cv2.contourArea(contour) to check what is going into the function.